# youtube mobile style navigation with jquery mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, navigation

I currently using jquery mobile and want to achieve the top navigation as youtube mobile with 2 icons at the right side (picture below)

[image]

So i try using this code below, but only one icon appeared.

```
<h1>Youtube Mobile</h1>
<a href="index.html" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse" class="ui-btn-right jqm-home">Menu</a>
<a href="search.html" data-icon="search" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse" class="ui-btn-right jqm-home">Search</a>
```

Anyone can help me solve this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both buttons are there. They are just being absolutely positioned one on top of another. Add the class 'grid' to your grid button. Then use `.grid.ui-btn-right{right:30px;}` to position your grid just left of search button. Here is a fiddle demonstrating this http://jsfiddle.net/codaniel/JMKss/1/